# Where is this function differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm doing homework and I am not sure how to check where this function is differentiable:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+n^2} $$
$$ x \in \mathbb{R}$$

I also don't really know what definitions I need to use. Since my studies is completely online, I lost track of all the material. Could you help me a bit?

Comment: perhaps this will help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312130/proving-an-infinite-series-is-differentiable

Comment: So I need to find the first derivative?
Which leads me to $$ \frac{-2x}{(x^2+n^2)^2} $$

but how do I continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**We will use the derivation under sum theorem**

Let $$  f_n(x) \triangleq \dfrac{1}{x^2+n^2} $$

1. You serie converges pointwise at $x=0$.
2. The derivative of $f_n$ exists and is

   $  f_n'(x) \triangleq \dfrac{-2x}{(x^2+n^2)^2} $

---

Let $K$ a compact of $\mathbb{R}-]0,1[$.

You have $ |f_n'(x)|= \left|\dfrac{-2x}{(x^2+n^2)^2}\right|\leq \left|\dfrac{-2x}{2x^2n^2}\right|\leq_K \dfrac{1}{\min(K)n^2} $

So $\sum f_n'$ converges uniformaly on such  $K$

---

On $[0,1]$

$$|f_n'(x)| \leq \dfrac{1}{n^2}$$

So it converges absolutely on whole $\mathbb{R}$

---

**Conclusion**

$$S\triangleq\sum f_n$$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$

$$ S' \triangleq\sum f_n' $$